# How to use Web Crypto API (or something similar) just to store data that can't be easily transferred?

Tags: javascript, cryptoapi

My requirement is to store UUID-like on client's web browser to identify user's machine (web browser copy in this case). Let's say, if IT guy comes to fix a laptop of HR manager, they could easily view username/password saved in web browser and use that credential on his PC later. My idea is to simply save an UUID in web browser's local storage and send it to verify at backend server. If username or password or UUID does not match, deny access. The problem is local storage can be viewed and re-created by IT guy  easily.

After Google, I believe that Web Cryto API is the way to go. It can be used to store encrypted object in IndexedDB with extracable = false, but can read via JavaScript, I hope. Unfortunately, most of online article are talking about encrypting/decrypting data which is too much for me. I just want **to store data that can't be transferred to another machine easily, but can read with JavaScript.** That's it.

Can anyone provide sample code or blog post to achieve this? Thank you.

PS 1) I know about web browser fingerprint concept, but it's not a solution since fingerprint value keeps changing from time to time.

PS 2) My JavaScript on production environment will be obfuscated and/or webpacked and/or made-confused by my own algorithm. Yes, it can be reverted-engineering by webapp developer, but not by most of users in the organization, I think.

Comment: `they could easily view username/password saved in web browser` That's why you don't store sensitive information anywhere in a browser. Ever. Not in the localStorage, not in cookies, nowhere.

Comment: that's also why you should always click "logout", to invalidate your token or whatever may be hanging in the browser.

Comment: You should use a proper auth mechanism like JWT or cookies. If your company is using o365, you can challenge with basic auth (win auth) to generate the token. But you can also use something like Firebase.

Comment: Hi, yes now I'm using JWT and it works fine. But most users like saving credential in web browser for their convenience. As a software developer, I thinks there might be a good way to solve this issue while system still friendly to user (allow them to save credential in web browser in this case).

Comment: And please come back to the question, is Web Crypto API capable to do this? Or any other technique recommend?